# Profiling `if(x)` VS `if(x===undefined)`

Tags: javascript, profiling

```
<script>
    function f(){
        var t=document.getElementById("t");
        var g=t.asdfg;
        var a=new Date().getTime();
        for(var x=0;x<100000000;++x){
            if(g===undefined);
            //if(g);
        }
        var b=new Date().getTime();
        alert(b-a);
    }
</script>
<body onload="f();">
    <input id="t"/>
</body>
```

in Firefox `if(g)` is slower than `if(g===undefined)` . I'm wondering does anyone know any good explanation why this is the case?

in Chrome `if(g)` is faster than `if(g===undefined)` . I'm wondering does anyone know any good explanation why this is the case?

I'm not arguing that we should use one over the other.. i'm just interested in the *theory*

Arguably different browsers have different implementations but any *theory* on any browser would be worthy of an answer

Comment: For benchmarks like this, you may want to use http://jsperf.com/ (I'm not affiliated, just a fan).

Answer (score 6):

There is no keyword `undefined` in javascript, it does not work like `null` does.

When you use

```
if(g===undefined)
```

`undefined` will be parsed as an identifier. Therefore, the interpreter must check for existance of the `undefined` variable in the global (window) scope. This lookup takes some time.

IMHO, the more correct way to check for undefinedness is (though not necessarily faster)

```
if(typeof(g) === 'undefined')
```

On the other hand, the expression `if(g)` is most likely implemented as an implicit cast to a boolean, which of course also takes some time.

So my guess is that these two different operations are not equally fast in the Firefox and Chrome engines.

Comment: with some profiling i believe the `typeof` operator isn't very fast too. just my 2c

Comment: Agreed. The main issue with the performance of typeof is probably the string comparison

Comment: uh actually my point was the `typeof` operator isn't very fast = is slow. string comparison depends alot on the string length. since "undefined" is a fairly short string, the `typeof` operator definitely has more overhead here. IE/FF/Chrome (the top 3 browsers) proved me right though to be fair, Opera/Safari proved me wrong. and yes this has nothing to do with the question.